# Prove a sequence to be convergent when explicit expression is not given

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This question is based on an exercise in real analysis.

> Given $a_n \geq 0$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose the limit of $b_n = (-1)^na_n$ exists. Prove that $a_n$ converges to zero.

**THOUGHTS**:

By definition of limits, I need to show that given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$,
$$
|a_n-0|<\epsilon.
$$

But I do not have any *explicit* expressions for the two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$. How can I prove the convergence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By contraposition we need to consider $3$ cases

- $a_n \to L\neq 0 \implies b_n = (-1)^na_n$ doesn't converge
- $a_n \to \infty \implies b_n = (-1)^na_n$ doesn't converge
- $a_n$ doesn't converge $\implies b_n = (-1)^na_n$ doesn't converge

to be proved considering the two subsequences for $n=2k$ even and $n=2k+1$ odd.

Comment: I think prove that $b_n$ converges to zero and then deduce it to $a_n$ is a good approach. How can I prove $b_n$ converges to zero

Comment: We need to prove $$b_n = (-1)^na_n \to L \implies a_n \to 0$$ Proceeding by contradiction we need to assume that $$a_n \not \to 0 \implies \lim b_n = (-1)^na_n \; \text{doesn't exist}$$ and for $a_n \not \to 0$ we have three cases (for $a_n\ge 0$).

Comment: Can we come up with two cases where n is even and n is odd? If n is even, then $a_n = b_n$ and $a_n = -b_n$ otherwise

Comment: @hck007 Yes exactly, indeed by that simple observation we can conclude that each one of the three case lead to a contradiction.

Comment: here is my formal proof by contradiction. I suppose not. Since $b_n$ is convergent, any subsequence must converge and have the same limit. For case 1, I take two subsequence of $b_n$ to be $b_{2k}$ and $b_{2k + 1}$. thus, one even subsequence converges to L but another goes to -L. Contradiction. For case 2, since both subsequences go to infinity but $b_n$ does have a limit. Contradiction. The same for case 3. Is my proof correct?

Comment: @hck007 For case 2 $b_{2k}=\to \infty$ and $b_{2k+1}\to -\infty$ therefore limit for $b_n$ doesn't exists. Note that usually when we say that the limit exists we mean that it can be finite (the sequence converges) or it can be infinte (the sequence diverges). We say that the limit doesn't exists in the other cases (for example the sequence "oscillates").

Comment: @hck007 For case three we have that $b_{2k}=a_{2k}$ and $b_{2k+1}=-a_{2k+1}$ can't have the same finit value otherwise $a_n$ would be convergent.

Comment: How do you show that $b_n = (-1)^na_n$ where $a_n$ goes to infinity does not have a limit?

Comment: @hck007 Simply because $b_{2k}=\to \infty$ but $b_{2k+1}\to -\infty$ and for the uniqueness of the limit $b_n$ has no limit.

Comment: I got you! You mean by the uniqueness of limit, the sequence must have at most one limit. But the subsequences have two different limits, which is a contradiction. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes exactly! You are welcome. Bye

Comment: Note that this kind of proof by contraposition to be precise and not by contradiction.

Comment: @Jack Yes of course! I agree. Thanks

Comment: @Jack Yes I know that. Unfortunately many users here consider with a negative perspective simpler problems and the use of MSE for an educational purpose. Thanks for the invitation to the chat, I'll tale a look. Bye

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence converges, every sub sequences converge, and converge toward the same limit.

In particular $(d_n=b_{2n})$ and $(e_n=b_{2n+1})$ converge to the same limit l. You should be able to show that $l = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $L=\lim b_n$ is positive (the case for negative $L$ is similar).

Let $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|b_n-L| < L =: \epsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Then let $n>N$

$$0 = L-\epsilon < (-1)^n a_n < L+\epsilon = 2L  $$

Then $n$ is even and $n+1$ is odd, so

$$0 < -a_{n+1} < 2L$$

Contradiction.

Once it is established $L=0$ then it's a simple matter of $|a_n-0| = |b_n| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that
$$\text{if}\quad l=\lim_n x_n\quad\text{then}\quad l=\lim_n x_{n+1}\quad\text{as well}.\tag{$*$}$$
Let $L=\lim_n (-1)^n a_n$. Then by ($*$), $L=\lim_n (-1)^{n+1}a_{n+1}$. But then
\begin{align*}
0&=L-L\\
&=\lim_n(-1)^{n+1}a_{n+1}-(-1)^na_n\\
&=\lim_n(-1)^{n+1}(a_{n+1}+a_n) \tag{$**$}
\end{align*}
Taking absolute values in ($**$) yields
$$0=\lim_n(a_{n+1}+a_n)\tag{$***$}$$
because $a_n,a_{n+1}\geq 0$. But since $0\leq a_n\leq a_n+a_{n+1}$, then ($***$) gives us $0=\lim_n a_n$.